# Proof: Convergence of an equation and show the first derivative is bounded

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

We have the following equation

\begin{equation}
x(k+1)=\arccos\bigg( -\frac{1}{2(Dr^{\frac {|\sin(2x(k)+\theta)|}{M\sin x(k)\sqrt{A+2B\cos(2x(k)+\theta)}}}+1)} \bigg)  \nonumber
\end{equation}

$A,B,D,r,M,\theta$ are constants.

```
x[k + 1] ==
        ArcCos[-1/(Abs[Sin[2 x[k] + θ]]/(
        2 (d r^(m Sin[x[k]] Sqrt[a + 2 b Cos[2 x[k] + θ]])) + 1))]
```

The equation above can be written as $x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$. How do we show that it converges using *Mathematica*?

How do we find the first derivative of the equation given above using *Mathematica*?

Also, is that possible to show that the first derivative is bounded?

Comment: Please _at least_ write down the Mathematica code for your sequence. And show what have you tried, if possible.

Comment: As a rule of thumb do not use upper case letters for names of parameters, variables, functions, etc. In your case `D` is a built-in predicate.

Comment: What would you consider normal values for {a, d, r, \[Theta], m, b}? You need to constrain these, since otherwise the answer from the right hand side is complex-valued.

Comment: @bills $\theta <2\pi/3$ and $A,B,D>0$, $0\leq r \leq 2$ and $\pi/2 < x_{k}<2\pi/3$

Comment: @bills http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514426/how-to-show-the-convergence-of-an-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is straightforward: write the equation explicitly as a function of x:

```
f[x_] := ArcCos[-1/(Abs[Sin[2 x + θ]]/(2 (d r^(m Sin[x] Sqrt[ a + 2 b Cos[2 x + θ]]))+1))]
```

and take the derivative:

```
FullSimplify[D[f[x], x]]
```

Evan after simplification it's not very simple.

Using a set of parameters that seems to lie in the designated set
    {a, d, r, θ, m, b} = {1, 1, 1, Pi/3, 1, 1}
I get f[5 Pi/8] as
    3.14159 - 1.79944 I
so either something is wrong with the `f[]` as written or the bounds on the parameters are incorrect.

Comment: is that possible to show that $D[f[x]]$ bounded?

Comment: Please check the equation. It is returning complex values -- this means that there is something seriously wrong with the setup.